# multiple strings to a single var in javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created an input and a button. When you press the button, if you put one of 3 states in it makes certain panels appear and disappear.  This part works fine.  The only problem is that it only accepts the input if you do a lowercase `nj`.

How can I change my code to accept both lowercase, upper case, and the word `New Jersey` spelled out in full?

```
var stateSearch, searchButton, nj, pa
nj = "nj";
stateSearch = $("#stateSearch").val();

if (stateSearch === nj) {
    $(".nj").fadeIn(2000);
    $(".pa").fadeOut(500);
    $(".ny").fadeOut(500);
    return;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a dictionary to accept these different versions

```
var acceptState = {
    "NJ" : true,
    "NEW JERSEY" : true
};
```

And then use toUpperCase when you check this dictionary

```
if (acceptState[stateSearch.toUpperCase()]) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can force the user input to lower case to match the string you're testing against by using `toLowerCase()`. Try this:

```
if (stateSearch.toLowerCase() === nj) {
    // your code...
}
```